# How can I get the RabbitMQ queue acknowledge statistics

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using pika and want to know how to get the acknowledge statistics.

I have installed management plugin from which I can see the acknowledge statistics, but I want to access it directly through a library; such as pika.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:**

Today I would use the inbuilt [Prometheus plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html) to gather detailed statistics instead.

---

If you want to get the data you can simply use a HTTP client in Python and use the RabbitMQ Management API to retrieve the data for your own usage.

The api is pretty easy to use, but this particular feature is not necessarily well documented. You can however easily map the information you need and use it to generate the kind of information you need.

**You simply call the queue information like this:**

- `http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/Test`

Simply replace `Test` with the name of the queue you need to collect data from.

**You then add a couple of options to get more detailed information:**

- `?lengths_age=60&lengths_incr=5&msg_rates_age=60&msg_rates_incr=5`
- e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/queue_name?lengths_age=60&lengths_incr=5&msg_rates_age=60&msg_rates_incr=5`

**The output would look something like this:**

```
{"memory": 21816,
 "message_stats":
     {
         "publish": 4,
         "publish_details":
             {
              "rate": 0.0,
              "samples": [....]
         },
         "messages": 4,
         "messages_details": 
             {
                 "rate": 0.0, 
                 "samples": [....],
                 "avg_rate": 0.0, 
                 "avg": 4.0},
         "messages_ready": 4,
         "messages_ready_details": {
             "rate": 0.0,
             "samples": [....],
             "avg_rate": 0.0,
             "avg": 4.0
         },
.....
```

If you are looking for an overview of the RabbitMQ server, rather than a specific queue you can use this api call.

- `http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/overview?lengths_age=60&lengths_incr=5&msg_rates_age=60&msg_rates_incr=5`

General documentation on the API is available [here](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html).